# Jquery Add New Element at Position of Dragged Element

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add each new item at the same position, even though the original element has been repositioned by dragging. At present only he first appended item displays where I want. Please help?

```
$("#buttons > button").click(function(){
     var col = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase().substr(3);
     var image = images[col];
     console.log(image);
 $('#sandpit').append('<div class="draggable newTriangle"><img src="images/' + image + '" width="25" height="25"></div>');

 makeDraggable();

});
```

CSS:

```
.newTriangle{
    position: relative;
    left: 575px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: in this case a JSFiddle might make it easier to answer the question. In some cases I might transfer the code to JSFiddle myself, but I'd have to create the missing elements (although posting only the relevant code was the right thing to do).

Answer (score 0):

The position of the new triangles (.newTriangle) has to be absolute, since now it's relative they can't overlap each other. To have the new div's contained in the parent div, the parent div has to have a relative position.

```
.newTriangle{
   position: absolute;
   left: 575px;
   top: 0px;
}
```